# Checking if the password is meeting the length condition

Tags: php, passwords, string-length

So before I added this new `if` statement to my code where it checks the string length, it was working perfectly fine. I have now tried to add an extra `if` statement to see if the password length on the form meets the condition of being between 6 and 32 characters long, but for some reason I am still receiving an error( 500 server error).

I have tried to read the code over and over, but cannot seem to spot what is throwing me this error. I am not sure if it is where I have placed this statement that could be causing this or something smaller and simpler than that.

Would appreciate some advice over this. Thank you in advance.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 0);
error_reporting(-1);

require 'connection.php';

$message = '';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
  //var_dump($password, $confirmpassword);
  if(strlen($password) < 6 || strlen($password) > 32):

    if($password == $confirmpassword):


    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Role, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :role, :email, :username, :password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $hashPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_POST['firstname']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $_POST['lastname']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':role', $_POST['role']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $hashPassword);

    if ($stmt->execute()):
      echo 'Well done! You have successfully registered with us!';
      header('Location:loginPage.php');
    else:
      echo 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
      //$message = 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
    endif;
  else:
    echo 'Your password must be between 6 to 32 characters.';
  else:
    echo 'Your passwords do not match, please enter them correctly.';
    header('Location:registerPage.php');
  endif;
endif;
endif;
```

Comment: Check your logs, [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) - it will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire and [don't limit passwords] (http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html).

Comment: Missed it @Qirel, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @user3453342 From a quick count (I may be wrong), but seems like you have a `endif` missplaced (you have two `else`s in a row)

Comment: that error reporting *should* have been throwing you a few things here, but you failed to share that with us.

Comment: @Qirel So I have checked my error logs and this is what I have found from it  `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /apps/help-i-need-a-tutor/web/register.php on line 42, referer: http://hinat.local/registerPage.php`.

Comment: I have commented out the `else:
    echo 'Your password must be between 6 to 32 characters.';` which allows it work but doesn't do the check I have put in place which is to see if the character is less than 6 or greater than 32 characters long. It just registers the user automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick glance on possible cause of errors:

- Line 28 has an `else` statement followed by another `else` on line 30.
- Line 32 has `header(Location:)` call after an echo, which won't work because `header()` cannot have anything output/printed before it.

Also, usually internal error (500) is caused by Apache's misconfiguration instead of code error. Have you tried to remove your extra `if()` statement and see if your code works?

Edit with code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 0);
error_reporting(-1);

require 'connection.php';

$message = '';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
  //var_dump($password, $confirmpassword);
  if(strlen($password) < 6 || strlen($password) > 32):

    if($password == $confirmpassword):
      $sql = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Role, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :role, :email, :username, :password)";
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $hashPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

      $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_POST['firstname']);
      $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $_POST['lastname']);
      $stmt->bindParam(':role', $_POST['role']);
      $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
      $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
      $stmt->bindParam(':password', $hashPassword);

      if ($stmt->execute()):
        echo 'Well done! You have successfully registered with us!';
        header('Location:loginPage.php');
      else:
        echo 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
        //$message = 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
      endif;
    else:
      echo 'Your password must be between 6 to 32 characters.';
    endif;

  // ========= You need to add `endif` (above) before starting another `else`
  else:
    echo 'Your passwords do not match, please enter them correctly.';
  endif;

  header('Location:registerPage.php');
endif;
```

Edit 2, same code but with additional visual block line (warning: will produce syntax error):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 0);
error_reporting(-1);

require 'connection.php';

$message = '';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
  //var_dump($password, $confirmpassword);
  if(strlen($password) < 6 || strlen($password) > 32):
  | 
  |  if($password == $confirmpassword):
  |  |  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Role, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :role, :email, :username, :password)";
  |  |  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  |  |  $hashPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  |  |  $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_POST['firstname']);
  |  |  $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $_POST['lastname']);
  |  |  $stmt->bindParam(':role', $_POST['role']);
  |  |  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
  |  |  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
  |  |  $stmt->bindParam(':password', $hashPassword);

  |  |  if ($stmt->execute()):
  |  |    echo 'Well done! You have successfully registered with us!';
  |  |    header('Location:loginPage.php');
  |  |  else:
  |  |    echo 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
  |  |    //$message = 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
  |  |  endif;
  |  else:
  |    echo 'Your password must be between 6 to 32 characters.';
  |  endif;
  |
  // ========= You need to add `endif` (above) before starting another `else`
  else:
    echo 'Your passwords do not match, please enter them correctly.';
  endif;

  header('Location:registerPage.php');
endif;
```

Comment: Without the extra `if()` statement concerning the string length, it has worked fine. Even where the `header(Location:)` is placed it has worked normally, I haven't had any issues with where it was located but just the extra if statement which after checking the error logs it said there was an issue with my `else` statement on line 42.

Comment: You have an `else` followed by another `else` before an `endif`. I have corrected your code to include indentation for clarity and moved the extra `endif` from line 46 to line 40 (see edit to my answer). Please give it a try.

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much for your help. I have tried out your code and it has worked successfully.  My only problem is that it seems to be ignoring my `if` statement completey and still allows data to be added to the database regardless of whether the password characters are less than 6 or greater than 32.

Comment: Hi again, I've tinkered a little with the code structure just to test and see if I would get a different output. So for example I have replaced the last `else` statement  with  `else:
      echo 'Your password must be between 6 to 32 characters.';
    endif;` So that it would match the right if statement and also changed `if(strlen($password) < 6 || strlen($password) > 32):` to `if(strlen($password) < 6 && strlen($password) > 32):` which has now given me the else statement desired. The real problem here is that it's doing the oppoisite of my previous statement and blocking any submission.

Comment: I have added line to show you where you logic blocks go. As you go through your code, you'll check: if the length is not between 6 and 32, your error is "your passwords do not match", whereas if password != confirmpassword, your error is "your password must be between 6 to 32 chars". Also, I have modified the code to go back to registerPage.php as I think you need it regardless of which error you got.

Comment: Just noticed your comment where you have swapped the error message. Anyway, your length checking cannot work because you can't have length that is both less than 6 and more than 32 characters. What you need is to check if the password is longer than 6 AND shorter than 32: `if (strlen($password) > 6 && strlen($password) < 32)):`

Comment: Hi Sutandiono, thanks so much for your help. I greatly appreciate it, everything was successful and the checks work fin. :)